# Google Directions Service wrong waypoint order returned

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-api-2, google-directions-api

I have two request where I only changed order in which i send waypoints in second request I moved waypoint one to position two and the other three waypoints are the same, but "waypoint_order" returned by google changed not as expected.
Request 1:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=44.7808248%2020.0845678&destination=44.7796273%2020.0838463&waypoints=optimize:true%7C44.7806935%2020.0844793%7C44.7803089%2020.0842888%7C44.7798215%2020.0839079%7C44.7800804%2020.0841333%7C44.7805088%2020.0843773&key=YOUR_API_KEY
Response 1:
"waypoint_order" : [ 0, 4, 1, 3, 2 ]

Request 2:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=44.7808248%2020.0845678&destination=44.7796273%2020.0838463&waypoints=optimize:true%7C44.7803089%2020.0842888%7C44.7806935%2020.0844793%7C44.7798215%2020.0839079%7C44.7800804%2020.0841333%7C44.7805088%2020.0843773&key=YOUR_API_KEY
Response 2:
"waypoint_order" : [ 1, 4, 0, 3, 2 ]

I expected just first two waypoints to be switched in second response.
Am I missing something? 
I took the simliest example i could, this happens with more waypoints too. Thanks in advance!

[Red marker is Destination, Green origin, Orange ones are waypoints. As said I picked the simpliest example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izDzs.png)

Comment: What about setting `optimize` to `false`??

Comment: @MrUpsidown well I'm actually using this so I can optimize route for users. Maybe I did't make it clear enough, only thing that I'm using is waypoint_order and I need it correct and not depending on my sending order. If i set it to false then I'm not doing anything. Thanks for your trouble anyways.

Comment: Are you sure you understood the purpose of the optimization option? Also please define "correct" when the optimization is done by the API on multiple parameters.

Comment: Documentation says: By default, the Directions service calculates a route through the provided waypoints in their given order. Optionally, you may pass optimize:true as the first argument within the waypoints parameter to allow the Directions service to optimize the provided route by rearranging the waypoints in a more efficient order. (This optimization is an application of the traveling salesperson problem.) Travel time is the primary factor which is optimized, but other factors such as distance, number of turns and many more may be taken into account [...]

Comment: @MrUpsidown Yes I'm sure, thats exactly what I want to give to my users. Users points rearanged in the more efficient order. I'm not sure that you understand my problem here? I'm sending 5 same points just in different order and google is rearranging them differently depending on order that I'm sending them.

Comment: @MrUpsidown by "correct" I mean more efficient as said in documentation

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet where we see this on a map?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I think code is not needed here I'm just changing the labels on markers depending on waypoint order. I will edit my question and add prtsc of map with drawn labels marked with waypoint_order number.

Comment: Code **is** needed for any question asking why some code is not working. Further to that, maybe YOU should put them on a map to see what's happening. For me the waypoints order is perfectly fine for your second request, which is `[1, 4, 0, 3, 2]` which is going from the closest to the furthest from origin.

Comment: I'm not having problem with any code thats why code is not needed. In first request "0" waypoint is 44.7806935 20.0844793 and it's positioned on 3rd place in waypoint_order, than in second request that same lat and lon are on position "1" and its on 1st position in waypoint_order. I hope someone will come up with explanation. In the mean time i'm gonna contact google supp and leave their answer here. Again thank you very much for your trouble, i'm sorry that i'm not able to explain this any better.

Comment: *In first request "0" waypoint is 44.7806935 20.0844793 and it's positioned on 3rd place in waypoint_order, than in second request that same lat and lon are on position "1" and its on 1st position in waypoint_order* - **No**. It's not. Read your own code again...

Comment: To clarify my "No." above: The waypoint we are talking about is `44.7806935 20.0844793`. In **first request**, it is waypoint 0 and it is in the FIRST place in waypoint order. And in **second request**, it is waypoint 1, and it is in the FIRST place in waypoint order. See my answer as well.

Comment: I am being rude??? You can't read your own code back and I am being rude? Wow. You know what's going to happen, right?

Answer (score 1):

Well... either I don't understand you, or you don't understand me, or you don't understand the documentation. Let's plot your examples on a map then you will tell me what is wrong.

**First request**

Waypoints order as you entered them:

```
0. 44.7806935, 20.0844793   
1. 44.7803089, 20.0842888   
2. 44.7798215, 20.0839079   
3. 44.7800804, 20.0841333   
4. 44.7805088, 20.0843773
```

```js
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService;
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
  });

  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {

  var waypts = [];

  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7806935, 20.0844793)
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });
  createMarker(stop, '0');

  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7803089, 20.0842888)
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });
  createMarker(stop, '1');

  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7798215, 20.0839079)
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });
  createMarker(stop, '2');

  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7800804, 20.0841333)
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });
  createMarker(stop, '3');

  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7805088, 20.0843773)
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });
  createMarker(stop, '4');

  start = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7808248, 20.0845678);
  end = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7796273, 20.0838463);

  createMarker(start, 'A');
  createMarker(end, 'B');

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

      console.log(response);

      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
    }
  });
}

function createMarker(latlng, label = null) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    label: label
  });
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize">
</script>
```

**Second request**

Waypoints order as you entered them, and in brackets, the order they were in the first request:

```
0. 44.7803089, 20.0842888 [1]
1. 44.7806935, 20.0844793 [0]
2. 44.7798215, 20.0839079 [2]  
3. 44.7800804, 20.0841333 [3]  
4. 44.7805088, 20.0843773 [4]
```

```js
var directionDisplay;
var directionsService;
var map;

function initialize() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    suppressMarkers: true
  });

  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 3,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), myOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {

  var waypts = [];

  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7803089, 20.0842888)
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });
  createMarker(stop, '0');

  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7806935, 20.0844793)
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });
  createMarker(stop, '1');

  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7798215, 20.0839079)
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });
  createMarker(stop, '2');

  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7800804, 20.0841333)
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });
  createMarker(stop, '3');

  stop = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7805088, 20.0843773)
  waypts.push({
    location: stop,
    stopover: true
  });
  createMarker(stop, '4');

  start = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7808248, 20.0845678);
  end = new google.maps.LatLng(44.7796273, 20.0838463);

  createMarker(start, 'A');
  createMarker(end, 'B');

  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    waypoints: waypts,
    optimizeWaypoints: true,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.WALKING
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {

      console.log(response);

      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      var route = response.routes[0];
    }
  });
}

function createMarker(latlng, label = null) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: latlng,
    map: map,
    label: label
  });
}
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initialize">
</script>
```

As far as I can tell, the waypoints order **is perfectly fine** in both responses.

Comment: If you start your drive from point A to point B in your example and u need to deliver package on these 5 points would you go in this order?

Comment: Well... unless I want to do some sightseeing around, then yes. Again... what is wrong with the order given in the response for both examples? I see them ordered in a straight line, closest one from start being first waypoint, second closest being second, and so on, in both cases.